# Ações da fila de análise de baixa qualidade, faltam opções

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Abri a fila de análise de "Publicações de baixa qualidade" e me deparei com essa pergunta (e outras similares que já vi anteriormente):

[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/405589/laravel-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-campo-formatado-com-moeda-br/526681#526681)

[image: print]

Ao meu ver, posso estar enganado, nenhuma das 3 ações se aplica:

- 1. não me parece ok, faltam esclarecimentos, melhorar a pergunta;
- 2. não faz sentido eu revisar e adicionar lá detalhes, isso deve ser feito por quem respondeu;
- 3. também não faz sentido remover, é uma tentativa de responder a pergunta, mas está pobre, falta mais detalhes, esclarecimento, links, etc.

Eu penso que poderia existir mais duas opções:

- Converter em comentário, já que não é uma resposta com detalhes que realmente esclareça como resolver;
- Adicionar um comentário do tipo "Sua resposta requer esclarecimentos, elabore melhor... bla bla bla";

Existe um entendimento do que fazer nesse caso nessa análise? Pensando que não faz sentido editar, pelas demais opções, ou deixamos com está, e fica com essa baixa qualidade, ou excluir, que vai perder uma resposta com uma solução, porém mal explicada.

Comment: Eu desabafei sobre isso no chat sobre as filas de primeiras respostas e primeiras perguntas. Nenhuma opção me pareciam corretas e não conseguia progredir, me foi um entrave.

Comment: O comentário é adicionado com sinalização ou negativação, mas não tem mesmo aí. O pedido para deixar os usuários converterem em comentário é antigo, mas nunca quiseram fazer. Não faz sentido permitir a remoção mas não converter em comentário. Por isso que as pessoas cansam de tentar fazer o site funcionar adequadamente. Eles mexem no site onde ninguém pediu e não mexem em coisas mais fáceis e óbvias. É cansativo quando o software não ajuda até em coisas simples assim.

Comment: *"Eles mexem no site onde ninguém pediu e não mexem em coisas mais fáceis e óbvias."*  é o clássico não arruma e ainda atrapalha :D

Comment: de qualquer forma, enquanto está assim o que vocês sugerem? penso que seria ir direto na pergunta sinalizar como "não é uma pergunta, deveria ser convertida para comentário". E se for isso, a fila deixa como ok, ou pula e espera a análise da sinalização?

Comment: De forma geral, quando a fila não dá a opção correta, eu faço fora dela (como aliás eu tenho feito com as filas novas também)

Comment: Por muitas razões eu sempre usei a fila como "índice", clicando no titulo com botão do meio para abrir em aba separada e tratar fora. Agora parece que está virando o único jeito de fazer.